# Equating wave and particle formulas

Tags: energy, particle-physics, waves

E=mc$^2$ and E=hf.

Let's equate them. What we get is mc=h/lambda.

But is equating equations from wave and particle nature right or wrong? What is the alternative?

Comment: Maybe from Compton experiment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering

Answer (score -1):

[*E=mc2*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html#c3)  gives the relativistic mass,

[image: relativistic mass]

which does not have much to do with particles at the quantum mechanical level and leads to wrong conclusions if used the way you use it.

*and E=hf* is the energy of a massless photon, [in the Planck hypothesis](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html) The  lorentz covariant  equation for involving energy and momentum and invariant mass is

[image: invar mass]

The length of the energy momentum four vector is the invariant mass of the particle, and for a zero mass particle the energy and momentum are equal for units where c=1.

In contrast to your formula,

> mc=h/lambda.

the [de Broglie wavelength](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html)

[image: de Broglie wavelength]

it is only the momentum of the massive particle that is involved, **not** the total energy ( i.e. kinetic + invariant mass) that comes from using wrongly the relativistic mass .

The wave particle duality for massive particles uses the de Broglie formula, which was [validated experimentally.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod1.html)